# Kafka consumer - why offset resetting is logged in heartbeat thread?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Kafka 2.0.0 and Spring-Kafka 2.1.10

So when i browse my consumer log I can occasionally see log like below:

> 2020-07-16 20:32:13,451 **kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread** |
> my-group-id INFO  internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
> groupId=my-group-id] Resetting offset
> for partition my-group-id-2 to offset 37231.

Does this mean the offset resetting happened on the heartbeat thread? This looks very weird though.

This only happened once at the startup of my consumer program. Following resets are no longer logged in heartbeat thread any more.

Comment: for me it seems like rebalancing log

Comment: @Deadpool This is the first time resetting right after my consumer started, so not really a rebalance but an initial offset reset. I can see that for other partitions this line is logged under `dataContainer-0-C-1` (i think that stands for spring listener container?), but for this one it's in heartbeat thread.